# Comparing the "severity" of words of amount, degree, etc

Tags: words, expressions, linguistics, pragmatics

I'm looking for lists of words/phrases of degree, ordered by how strong they are relative to each other.

For an example in English, I ran across this research recently: http://www.businessinsider.com/quantitative-perceptions-of-probability-words-2017-5

I was wondering if there are any similar lists for:

1. Degree... わずか　＜　なかなか　＜　とっても etc
2. Amount... すこし　＜　そこばく　＜　たくさん etc
3. Frequency... めったに　＜　よく　＜　しょっちゅう　＜　いつも etc
4. Severity/strength... やんわり　＜　つよく　＜　たいへん　etc
5. Surety... たしか　＜　きっと　＜　ひつぜん etc

By the way, I see a lot of questions about pairs of words on this list, i.e. "is this word more or less on the degree scale than this"... so if a good answer can be found that has a bunch of examples hierarchicalized, it might answer a lot of future questions all at once. 一石無限鳥 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Degree... わずか　＜　なかなか　＜　とっても etc

**暑｛あつ｝さ/寒｛さむ｝さ**
As for the degree of temperature, we say like 少｛すこ｝し暑｛あつ｝い / 少｛すこ｝し寒｛さむ｝い for *it's hot a little* / *it's cold a little*.

> Adverbs to describe the degeree of hotness/coldness are like:
>   **わずか**に ＜ ほんの少し ≒ 気持｛きも｝ち ＜ ちょっと ≒ 少し ＜ 大分｛だいぶ｝ ≒ **なかなか** ＜ いい加減｛かげん｝（に） ≒ 相当｛そうとう｝（に） ≒ かなり ＜ すごく ≒ とても/**とっても** ≒ うんと ＜ 無茶｛むちゃ｝苦茶｛くちゃ｝（に） ＜ 死｛し｝にそうに

Hierarchicalized adverbs written in the above list could be applied commonly to express the degree of amount, frequency, severity/strength and surety except for some adverbs. The typical exception is 死にそうに, that is used only in severity or in something like that.

Amount... すこし　＜　そこばく?(← obsolete word)　**かなり** ＜　たくさん etc
Frequency... めったに　＜　よく　＜　しょっちゅう　＜　いつも etc
Severity/strength... やんわり?　＜　つよく?　＜　たいへん　etc
Surety... たしか?　＜　きっと　＜　ひつぜん?　**確実｛かくじつ｝（に）** ＜ **絶対｛ぜったい｝（に）** etc